Extract data from d3.js interactive tree to CSV
I don't know if it a silly question but is it possible to extract the data from the nodes from a d3js interactive tree and convert it to CSV data?
It is possible to convert CSV data to d3.js tree by loading and transforming the flat data to nested data as shown below.
Creating a D3.js Collapsible Tree from CSV data
I tried the code below to create interactive tree but I am I have no idea what to do next.
https://plnkr.co/edit/P2Jcqh12cxVyToLdXun6?p=preview&preview
All I know is that some how I must fetch all the created nodes and get the values by object.values especially the parent and child relationship.
Any idea on how to do this? Detailed example will be great because I am  a newbie.

The plnkr code does not show a tree in the preview. Is that intentional?
